# How to do Elasticsearch range query the summation of two fields in Java API?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have two fields in my documents: `ACount` and `BCount`, I want to write a range query to get the documents where `sum(ACount + BCount) > 100` through Java API. I was trying to do something like 
`BoolQueryBuilder.must(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery(...).gte(100))`, but couldn't find a good way to do it. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use painless script for this.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "script": {
            "script": {
              "source": "(doc['ACount'].value + doc['BCount'].value) > params.count",
              "params": {
                "count": 100
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

You can use java client generate the above query.

Comment: Thanks! Just figured out the java query would be something like 
`private final BoolQueryBuilder query;
ScriptQueryBuilder rangeQuery = QueryBuilders.scriptQuery("doc['ACount'].value + doc['BCount'].value) > params.count");
query.must(rangeQuery);`

Comment: Glad it helped helped and you figured out the corresponding java code. Please feel free to upvote and accept the answer.